# What settings can I change in virtualized XP and W7 to minimise unnecessary image file differential size

Tags: backup, virtualization, pagefile, browser-cache

I have several virtualized instances of XP and W7 on KVM, and each week I take an LVM snapshot of the `qcow2` file and rsync it to a remote site. I'd like to reduce my bandwidth usage if possible - what can I change on those machines to minimise unnecessary changes in the `qcow2` file?

Should I:

1. reduce the cache size for the browser?
2. turn off the pagefile?

or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: While I am uncertain of the format KVM uses for the virtual harddisk, any suggestions about the guest OS's behavior will assume an object inside the guest OS corresponds to a certain area on the virtual harddisk itself. I'm curious if this assumption proves true.

Comment: `qcow2` is a copy-on-write filesystem. Writing to the pagefile for example will allocate new blocks, but release the old ones that can then be re-used.